# navigator.share() throw DOMException: Permission denied even on mobile

Tags: javascript, share, navigator

I have a NextJS app that fetches an API and receives a blob image.

Everything works correctly and I can see the image on the browser with the `<img src="blob:https://myurl.com/blob-id">`

I would like to create a button that share the image on Instagram story. I'm using the [`navigator.share()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share) API like

```
async function shareImage(imgLink: string, bindata: string) {
    console.log(`clicked shareImageAsset: ${imgLink}`);

    const binaryData = Buffer.from(JSON.parse(bindata));
    const blobImage = new Blob(
      [binaryData.buffer],
      { type: "image/jpeg" } /* (1) */
    );

    const fileName = imgLink.split("/").pop();
    const fileNameTrue: string = fileName ? fileName : "image.jpg";
    const filesArray = [
      new File([blobImage], fileNameTrue, {
        type: "image/jpeg",
        lastModified: Date.now(),
      }),
    ];
    console.log(filesArray);
    const shareData = {
      title: fileNameTrue,
      files: filesArray,
      url: document.location.origin,
    };
    if (navigator.canShare && navigator.canShare(shareData)) {
      await navigator.share(shareData);
    }
    // TODO implements a fallback to download the file
  }
```

but when the code executes the last line, `await navigator.share(shareData);` I got the error `navigator.share DOMException: Permission denied` even if I use it on mobile, with a smartphone with the Instagram app and a user logged in

### EDIT

I've also added in `next.config.js`

```
const nextConfig = {
  async headers() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        headers: [
          {
            key: "Permissions-Policy",
            value: "web-share=(*)",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

with no luck

Comment: MDN lists the window not having "transient activation" as one possible reason, and here shows how to check for it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Transient_activation

Comment: both `navigator.userActivation.isActive` and `navigator.userActivation.hasBeenActive` are `True`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the issue was just I was passing the filename without the extension.

Fixed adding `.jpg` at the end of the blob URL

```
const fileName = imgLink.split("/").pop();
const fileNameTrue: string = fileName ? fileName : "image";
const filesArray = [
  new File([blobImage], fileNameTrue + ".jpg", {
    type: "image/jpeg",
    lastModified: Date.now(),
  }),
```